# What is $\|\cdot \|_p$ for $0<p<1$?

Tags: normed-spaces

1) Is $$\|(x,y) \|_p=(|x|^p+|y|^p)^{1/p}$$ a norm for $0<p<1$ ? I can prove that $\|\lambda (x,y)\|_p=|\lambda |\|x\|_p$ and $\|x\|_p=0\iff x=0$. But I have difficulties to prove the triangle inequality.

2) Is this a type of non-convex norm ? Or non convex distance (if we set $d(x,y)=\|(x,y)\|_p$) ?

Comment: Well, you may start by studying the case $p=\frac{1}{2}$. What are your thoughts about 1) and 2) in such a case?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: Thank you for your answer. In fact I made a draw, and it looks to be a norm... but it's not convex... but I would like to have a confirmation...

Comment: No, it is not a norm.  One of the postulates for "norm" is $\|x+y\| \le \|x\|+\|y\|$.  That fails in this case.  What is it, then?  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasinorm

Answer (score 2):

If $p\in(0,1)$, the set $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: |x|^p+|y|^p=1\}$ is asteroid-shaped and convexity is clearly violated:

[image]

<sup>In this diagram I picked $p=\frac{1}{2}$.</sup>

In particular the midpoint between $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ has a $p$-norm which is always $>1$.
Similarly
$$ 1=\left\|\left(0,\tfrac{1}{2}\right)\right\|_p+\left\|\left(\tfrac{1}{2},0\right)\right\|_p \color{red}{<}\left\|\left(\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{2}\right)\right\|_p = 2^{\frac{1}{p}-1}$$
hence such "norms" do not induce distances.

Comment: thank you for your answer. So is it  norm ? Because @Omnomnomnom says that it has no sense for him... what do you think ? And if it's not a norm, why the notation $\|\cdot \|_p$ ? Moreover, such spaces are metrizable, no ?

Comment: Something I don't get $d(x,y)=\|(x,y)\|_{1/2}=(|x|^{1/2}+|y|^{1/2})^2$ is a distance, isn't it ? or it's maybe just $d(x,y)=|x|^{1/2}+|y|^{1/2}$ that is a distance ? How can you see from the that the triangle inequality doesn't hold ?

Answer (score 2):

The function you describe fails to be a norm for $0 < p < 1$.  In particular, you can verify that the triangle inequality will always fail since
$$
\|(1,1)\|_p > \|(1,0)\|_p + \|(0,1)\|_p
$$

Comment: To my knowledge, there is no commonly used notion of a "non-convex norm" or "non-convex distance".